# Set backgroung image in .php file

Tags: php, html

I downloaded this code:

```
    $image = ImageClass::getImage('bg.jpeg','myTitle');
$bg_img = explode(" ",$image);
$src = substr(strpos('"',$bg_img),strlen($bg_image)-1);
echo "<div style='background-image: url(".$src.");' ></div>
<?php

    /* 

*** OPTIONS ***/

    // TITLE OF PAGE
    $title = "ARQUIVOS PROPAR";

    // STYLING (light or dark)
    $color  = "dark";

    // ADD SPECIFIC FILES YOU WANT TO IGNORE HERE
    $ignore_file_list = array( ".htaccess", "Thumbs.db", ".DS_Store", "index.php", "flat.png", "error_log" );

    // ADD SPECIFIC FILE EXTENSIONS YOU WANT TO IGNORE HERE, EXAMPLE: array('psd','jpg','jpeg')
    $ignore_ext_list = array( );

    // SORT BY
    $sort_by = "name_asc"; // options: name_asc, name_desc, date_asc, date_desc

    // ICON URL
    //$icon_url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzxi5abx2gaj84q/flat.png?dl=0"; // DIRECT LINK
    $icon_url = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA+gAAAAyCAYAAADP7vEwAAAgAElEQVR4nOy9d5hdV3nv";

    // TOGGLE SUB FOLDERS, SET TO false IF YOU WANT OFF
    $toggle_sub_folders = true;

    // FORCE DOWNLOAD ATTRIBUTE
    $force_download = true;

    // IGNORE EMPTY FOLDERS
    $ignore_empty_folders = false;


// SET TITLE BASED ON FOLDER NAME, IF NOT SET ABOVE
if( !$title ) { $title = clean_title(basename(dirname(__FILE__))); }

?>
```

Th full code can be download here: https://github.com/halgatewood/file-directory-list/blob/master/index.php

I'm having problem with the start:

```
 $image = ImageClass::getImage('bg.jpeg','myTitle');
    $bg_img = explode(" ",$image);
    $src = substr(strpos('"',$bg_img),strlen($bg_image)-1);
    echo "<div style='background-image: url(".$src.");' ></div>
```

I want to put a picture as background, but it isn't happening. What's wrong?

---

Changed with the answer:

```
<?php
   echo "<div style='background-image: url('/bg.jpeg');' ></div>";
?>
<?php

    /* 

*** OPTIONS ***/

    // TITLE OF PAGE
    $title = "ARQUIVOS PROPAR";

    // STYLING (light or dark)
    $color  = "dark";
```

etc..

Comment: What is `ImageClass`? What does `ImageClass::getImage` return?

Comment: We'll also need the error that this script returns, we are not wizards after all

Comment: I'm still learning `.php`. I'm new. Just tried make the script recognize the image i want put `bg.jpeg` as background

Comment: _“Th full code can be download here”_ - that doesn’t even contain `ImageClass::getImage` anywhere, so we still don’t know what that actually is, or what it is supposed to return - which makes your whole question unanswerable to us.

Comment: Yes, i just put this adittional code in the start for the script recognize the background i want. But when i run nothing happen, it only show at the top `$image = ImageClass::getImage('bg.jpeg','myTitle'); $bg_img = explode(" ",$image); $src = substr(strpos('"',$bg_img),strlen($bg_image)-1); echo "`
Please check my site here: http://katzstorebrasil.com.br/PROPAR/

Comment: **i just put this adittional code in the start for the script recognize the background i want** This baffles me lol, can u explain why and how you decided to write `$image = ImageClass::getImage('bg.jpeg','myTitle'); ` please, did you copy-paste?

Comment: Just searched a lot in google how to put a background image in a `.php` file. So this code sounded nice and i heard that i need put it in the start of the script

Comment: Well first of all you should put your php code within the `<?php` tag. But even then I highly doubt it will work, but at least it will try to actually execute the php code then.

Comment: a class called `ImageClass` must exist in your code with whatever functionality you think it provides, for `$image = ImageClass::getImage('bg.jpeg','myTitle');` to work

Comment: tried to put ´<?php´ before, but nothing changed also

Comment: @I'mNotHere Whats the goal here, do you simply want to apply an img from your server as css background to an html element?

Comment: Yes, i heard that was an inline css element to put directly in the ´.php´ file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for all that,
What you desire to achieve is much simpler.

*Assuming this code is inside `index.php` and your server's directory structure:*

```
/some-folder/
/index.php
/bg.jpeg
```

Simply link it as its done in plain html —

```
<?php
   echo "<div style=\"background-image: url('/bg.jpeg');\" ></div>";
?>
```

If you wan't it do be dynamic, i.e, image files's name is inside a variable then,

```
<?php
   $my_image = 'bg.jpeg';
   echo "<div style='background-image: url($my_image);' ></div>";
?>
```

## Update:

Important Tip: All programming languages are executed line-by-line, this tip applies not only to PHP, but also HTML [Learn More](https://thesocietea.org/2015/07/programming-concepts-compiled-and-interpreted-languages/)

Assume for example, your page's html structure returned to the browser is as provide below and you want to apply background to `body` tag

```
<html>
  <head><head>
  <body>
    <nav>Some dummy navigation</nav>
    <div>welcome to my website</div>
    <footer>Copyright</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Simply copying and pasting my code to the top of page will result in

```
<div style="background-image: url('bg.jpeg');" ></div>
<html>
  <head><head>
  <body>
    <nav>Some dummy navigation</nav>
    <div>welcome to my website</div>
    <footer>Copyright</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**But that created a empty `div` tag at the top of html output, i wanted it to apply background to by `body` tag instead !!!?**

— This happened because `echo` is used to send output to the browser as soon as it is executed. So since you copied my code to the top of your script the html output is also at the top.

**But why did it echo `<div style="background-image: url('bg.jpeg');" ></div>` when i wanted it to apply to my page's `body`?**

— Because the echo statements reads `"<div style=\"background-image: url('bg.jpeg');\" ></div>";` as its output.

**Ok, but how to apply the background-image to body then??**

As mentioned earlier code is executed line-by-line, so in order to apply the style to pages's `body` tag you'll need to call it near your `body` tag and also modify it to not output the div it currently does.

So assuming your `index.php` is:

```
<?php
  $my_image = 'bg.jpeg';
  echo "<div style='background-image: url($my_image);' ></div>";
?>
<html>
  <head><head>
  <body>
    <nav>Some dummy navigation</nav>
    <div>welcome to my website</div>
    <footer>Copyright</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

You'll need to change it to —

```
<?php
  $my_image = 'bg.jpeg';
  // don't echo any thing here
?>
<html>
  <head><head>
  <body style="background-image: url('<?php echo $my_image; ?>')">
    <!-- apply the style to body -->
    <nav>Some dummy navigation</nav>
    <div>welcome to my website</div>
    <footer>Copyright</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully i explained it well :)

Comment: just put in the top above of the first `<?php` and nothing changed. The background keeps grey. Just check my edit

Comment: retry with the updated code, i fixed an error with your echo syntax

Comment: BTW looking at your [linked website](http://katzstorebrasil.com.br/PROPAR/) , I see the `index.php` file is inside a folder `PROPAR` so you'll need to change the image link from `/bg.jpeg` to `bg.jpeg` or `/PROPAR/bg.jpeg` assuming bg.jpeg is also in the folder called PROPAR

Comment: Your update after my answer is wrong, copy pasting my code as it is will just create an empty div with the correct background which will not be visible since it's empty. Modify the echo statement and its placement to wherever and whatever element whose background you need to change

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it. My english is bad...may you show me what i did wrong with your code?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Awsome! :)